# how handle forms Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Which is the best way to handle a form in react?

I'm starting with react, and when I search how handle forms the options that I found are by refs or with states, and events to update state and it is fine but when there are more than 10 fields? I need to get the value of each input to build a JSON because I'm working with an API.

Then which is the best way to handle a form in react? JavaScript? jQuery?
and even if a need to hide and show elements and other things.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using some library to handle your form e.g https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik